# Load pages via single state AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to create a method which can load the controller and template of each page on demand, when route changes and make the state url option have 2 parameters with the second one optional so that one of the pages can load additional information inside another ui-view based on that parameter. Can anyone help me?

Javascript:

```
.config(function config($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state("index", {
        url:"",
        controller:"FirstCtrl as first",
        templateUrl: "templates/first.html"
    })
    $stateProvider.state("second", {
        url:"/second",
        controller:"SecondCtrl as second",
        templateUrl: "templates/second.html"
    })
    $stateProvider.state("third", {
        url:"/third",
        controller:"ThirdCtrl as third",
        templateUrl: "templates/third.html"
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

js

```
$stateProvider
.state('report',{
views: {
  'filters': {
    templateUrl: 'report-filters.html',
    controller: function($scope){ ... controller stuff just for filters view ... }
  },
  'tabledata': {
    templateUrl: 'report-table.html',
    controller: function($scope){ ... controller stuff just for tabledata view ... }
  },
  'graph': {
    templateUrl: 'report-graph.html',
    controller: function($scope){ ... controller stuff just for graph view ... }
  }
}
})
```

Html

```
<body>
 <div ui-view="filters"></div>
 <div ui-view="tabledata"></div>
 <div ui-view="graph"></div>
</body>
```

please refer this link https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views

Comment: I want Create a method which can load the controller and template of each page on demand, when route changes and make the state url option have 2 parameters with the second one optional  so that one of the pages can load additional information inside another ui-view based on that parameter.